# Rails - routing error with friendly_id slug and nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to route to a nested resource from a resource using friendly_id. Below is the code:

routes.rb:

```
 resources :products do
   resources :reviews, except: [:index]
 end
```

rake routes:

```
new_product_review GET        /products/:product_id/reviews/new(.:format)
```

controller:

```
@review = Review.new(product_id: params[:product_id])
```

view button on the specific product page:

```
<%= link_to(raw("<button>Write a Review</button>"), new_product_review_path(@review.product_id, @review) ) %>
```

product URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/light-saber #just kidding
```

However, I am getting the error of:

```
undefined method `product_id'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update -----

Now in my controller I have:

```
before_filter :setup_product

@review = @product.reviews.new

def setup_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
end
```

I am still getting the same error though. My question explicitly is, since my URL is not passing in an integer ID because I am using friendly_id, is the param structured so that the controller can retrieve the product like I want?

UPDATE:

Now I am getting this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"reviews", :product=>nil}
```

I get this when I change the code in my Product page to:

```
<%= link_to(raw("<button>Write a Review</button>"), new_product_review_path(@review) ) %>
```

Comment: which is the exact line that is causing the issue?  the one in the contoller or the one in the route helper.  if you are creating a new product review, shouldn't it be `new_product_review_path(@product)`

Comment: Not sure - I don't get a specific line for the error, please see my latest update and thanks for taking a look!

Comment: no change it to `@product`, not `@review`. you want to create the review for the product, you don't have a review yet, hence the nil. i updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! What a dumb error on my part, I should've known to feed in the @product variable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the view (`products/show`) you need

```
   <%= link_to(raw("<button>Write a Review</button>"), new_product_review_path(@product) ) %>
```

then in your reviews controller you would need below.

try this, building it through the association

```
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@review = @product.reviews.new
```

you can even move the finding of the product into a before_action / before_filter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right association:

```
class Product
  has_many :reviews
  ...
end
```

That you ran the migrations: when you enter in the console, type `Review` and press enter. You should see the columns of the reviews table and there should be a `product_id` column.

And I'm not sure if it's a typo but in your routes it should be `resources :products do` and not `resources :productss do`. Note the double 's' in products.

Comment: Yes, the associations are there: Product 'has_many :reviews' and Review 'belongs_to :product'. And yes, that was a typo and yes I can confirm that the foreign key on the Reviews table for 'product_id' does exist. I think my setup is all correct, which is why I can't figure this out

Comment: Restart the server... just in case you haven't.

Comment: Yup, have done that after each code change just in case, but still getting the error